# Do skills you know but are not on your current skill list cost double points?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, skills

This is a rule I wanted to make sure about, I read somewhere that if you have a class with a certain skill on it, you can rank that up normally. However if you later go into a class that doesn't have it, the max ranks are the same but it costs 2 points for 1 rank unless you have something like able learner. Is this true and if so was there any errata to it?

Comment: Note: there are feats/ways to get bonus class skills. The *Able Learner* feat (Races of Destiny, p. 150) let a human or doppelganger have all skills be class skills :)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, this is all correct. No, it was never errata-ed. From the [SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/skillsSummary.htm):

> Regardless of whether a skill is purchased as a class skill or a cross-class skill, if it is a class skill for any of your classes, your maximum rank equals your total character level + 3.

So if you take a class which has Appraise as a class skill, the maximum number of skill points you can put in Appraise will always be your character level + 3, regardless of what classes you multiclass into.

> Each skill point you spend on a class skill gets you 1 rank in that skill. Class skills are the skills found on your character’s class skill list. Each skill point you spend on a cross-class skill gets your character ½ rank in that skill. Cross-class skills are skills not found on your character’s class skill list.

If you level as a class, each skill point you spend on a class skill gets you 1 rank, and each skill point you spend on a cross-class skill gets you a ½ rank. As you say, Able Learner changes this, but without it, cross-class skills require 2 skill points for each rank.

Comment: Which would make spells like Bard 6/Lyric Thaumaturge 4/ Sublime Chord 10 not Illegal, but substantially more of a pain to put together since Lyric thaumaturge doesn't have listen as a class skill. That's something to think about.

Comment: @Masakan Yep, that's where builds often do things like Bard 5/Lyric Thaumaturge 3/Bard 1 (put 4 skill ranks in Listen on a single level)/Sublime Chord 10. Alternatively, there's a few ways to get "X skill is always a class skill for you".